# Is it possible to change widget data of dashboards through the Smartsheet API?

Tags: smartsheet-api

I'm trying to automate regular creation of dashboards and seeing if it's possible to change the data in widgets programmatically through the API. Is it possible for this to be done?

I've tried programming with the API in both C# and Python, but always get stuck at finding a way to edit the contents of a widget.

Example of what I've tried in C#

```cs
Sight newSight = new Sight();

newSight.Name = "New Sight Name";
newSight.Id = 1111222223333;

Widget widg = new Widget();

widg.Type = Smartsheet.Api.Models.WidgetType.TITLE;
widg.Contents.HtmlContent = "<p>New Title</p>";

newSight.Widgets[0] = widg;

smartsheet.SightResources.UpdateSight(newSight);
```

Error message for this one I get is:

"System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

Smartsheet.Api.Models.Widget.Contents.get returned null."

For the HtmlContent line.

Another error message I've gotten is saying:

"Smartsheet.Api.InvalidRequestException: 'Unable to parse request. The following error occurred: Field "contents" was of unexpected type.'"

Which is when get a Sight and then try to change the contents in one of its widgets.

I'm also open to ideas on automating dashboard creations if possible.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

At this moment, it's only possible to update the name of a dashboard via the API. Additional functionality is on the roadmap, but for now, you'll need to either edit the widgets in the UI, or edit the source data, i.e., in the reports or sheets that populate the dashboard.

Comment: Is there any update on this? Is there any way to vote for items on the roadmap? Smartsheet has a lot of great features, but whenever I try to build automated workflows, I feel like an important part is missing.